# Trouble with Abstraction in MochaJS with Typescript and Axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, axios, mocha.js

New to typescript and mocha so hopefully this is an easy fix, I just can't seem to sort it out myself.

Given the following test case

```
it('should make a request', function (done) {
            console.log('CHECKPOINT ALPHA')
            var data = JSON.stringify({"REDACTED"});

            var headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }

            const response = request("post", rootUrl, headers, data, done)
            //todo add some validations
            done()
```

And the imported `request` function I have defined in another file as:

```
export function request(method, url, headers, data, done, statusCode = null) {
    console.log('CHECKPOINT BETA')
    let config : AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: method,
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        data : data
    };

    if(statusCode == null) {
        switch (method) {
            case "post":
                statusCode = 201;
                break;
            case "get":
                statusCode = 200;
                break;
            case 'patch':
                statusCode = 201;
                break;
            case 'put':
                statusCode = 201;
                break;
            case 'delete':
                statusCode = 204;
        }
    }

    console.log('CHECKPOINT CHARLIE')

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log('CHECKPOINT DELTA')
            assert(response.data.statusCode == statusCode)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
            done()
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('CHECKPOINT ECHO')
            fail(error)
            done()
        });
}
```

I would normally expect this to work and make a request.  Instead, the last log to the console is always checkpoint Charlie.  Likewise when running the debugger, it appears to skip the entire body of the axios call.

If I copy the contents of the request function into the body of the test case, everything works as expected, so it has something to do with the interplay of the two files.  My guess is that the `done()` method inside the axios block is not working the same as when it is inside the test file, causing the test to proceed and terminate execution before any code inside the axios block is properly executed.

Short version of the question -- how do I get the script to execute the code inside the axios block while keeping these in separate files?  I'd ideally like to return the response from axios to the test script

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Calling done() inside the original test case was telling mocha that the test case was finished executing before the async portion of the axios call had executed.  Removed that line and I got inside the block.

```
it('should make a request', function (done) {
            console.log('CHECKPOINT ALPHA')
            var data = JSON.stringify({"REDACTED"});

            var headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }

            const response = request("post", rootUrl, headers, data, done)
            //todo add some validations
```